# Bazel combine multiple rules in macro

Tags: bazel

My project structure has multiple sub-modules within it, these are essentially folders that are projects within their own right too.

For a given python project, each with sub projects. I would like to be able to write a macro that can create a set of actions to be taken on a given sub-project.

Essentially something along these lines inside the WORKSPACE:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_python//:python/pip.bzl",
   "pip_import"
)

pip_import(
   name = "foo",
   requirements = "@subprojectname//:requirements.txt",
)

load("@foo//:requirements.bzl", "pip_install")
pip_install()
```

There are multiple sub-projects I would like to do the above actions for.  However, if I put all the code into a function inside a bzl file.

pyrules.bzl

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_python//:python/pip.bzl",
   "pip_import"
)


def doit(name):
    pip_import(
       name = "foo",
       requirements = "@{repo}//:requirements.txt".format(repo=name)
    )

    load("@foo//:requirements.bzl", "pip_install")
    pip_install()
```

I cannot use the second, load command due to "syntax error at 'load': expected expression". Without then having multiple bzl files that are loaded into the parent WORKSPACE, is there any other way to create reusable chunks of logic?

**Update 1.**
Comments requested more information on the workflow. Warning, I have a non standard layout to how Bazel seems to be used else where i.e. not a monorepo. But it should come to a similar practical layout.

Projects are laid out as:

```
projectname/
    WORKSPACE
    BUILD
    src/
       stuff
    submodule/ # < git modules that are checked out into folder
        subproject1/
            BUILD
            src/
                stuff
        subproject2/
            BUILD
            src/ 
                stuff
```

Firstly, I have a repository_rule that is loaded in the WORKSPACE that finds all projects in the submodule folder and adds them as repositories. Within the subproject, some of these are python. I would like to load its requirements.txt files. Hence the overall question of where these requirements.txt files are and doing a pip install on them. Ideally I would like the py_library definitions in the subprojects BUILD files to know that there is a dependency on the requirements file of the subproject, but this likely doesn't matter as the parent BUILD file is the only thing that creates par_binaries and so on, so as long as the pip_install and setting the dependencies happens, the project itself should be usable.

Bazel doesn't appear to allow a child project to define their own repository actions like the above pip_install. I assume this is because you cant have repository actions in a BUILD file, and child WORKSPACE files don't seem to have any effect. So I ended up having to add this to the parent WORKSPACE file.

If it is in the parent WORKSPACE, I have to copy paste the pip actions for each of the subprojects I want to use.  However, I would prefer to just set up a general rule which would locate the requirements file and pip install them. Trying to make a macro from this however means that I cannot use the load call within it. All the pip  actions seem to need to interact with repository actions which then need to be called only from a parent WORKSPACE file.

Comment: Where do you want this pyrules.bzl file to sit? The parent WORKSPACE will reference them? How?

Comment: Good point. I did a very convoluted workaround to create bzl files on the fly that this then added as a fake repository. That is the only way I could get files resolved on startup instead of having to manually describe all the files in advance.

Comment: I think it would help if you can give more context about the flow you have in mind (let’s say after clone)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like any reasonable solution exists for this scenario. However, I think it's important to realize the rules that you depend on can be modified if you are willing to support them internally. I ended up modifying the piptool.py in the rules_python repository to add support for multiple requirements.txt files in a single call. Then added the following rules into my own rules repository that I use internally.

```
#
# Python
#

def _pip_import_requirements_impl(repository_ctx):
  """Core implementation of pip_import."""
  # Add an empty top-level BUILD file.
  # This is because Bazel requires BUILD files along all paths accessed
  # via //this/sort/of:path and we wouldn't be able to load our generated
  # requirements.bzl without it.
  repository_ctx.file("BUILD", "")

  # To see the output, pass: quiet=False
  result = repository_ctx.execute([
    "python3", repository_ctx.path(repository_ctx.attr._script),
    "--name", repository_ctx.attr.name,
    "--input"
    ] +
    [repository_ctx.path(r) for r in repository_ctx.attr.requirements] +
    [
      "--output", repository_ctx.path("requirements.bzl"),
      "--directory", repository_ctx.path("")
    ],
  quiet = repository_ctx.attr.quiet)

  if result.return_code:
    fail("pip_import failed: %s (%s)" % (result.stdout, result.stderr))


pip_import_requirements = repository_rule(
  attrs = {
    "quiet" : attr.bool(default = False),
    "requirements": attr.label_list(
       allow_files = True,
       mandatory = True,
     ),
     "_script": attr.label(
       executable = True,
       default = Label("@io_bazel_rules_python//tools:piptool.par"),
       cfg = "host",
     ),
  },
  implementation = _pip_import_requirements_impl,
)
```

Then I can do the following in my WORKSPACE.

```
pip_import_requirements(
  name = "py_requirements",
  requirements = [
    "@mycore//:requirements.txt",
    "@myother//:requirements.txt"
  ]
)

load(
    "@py_requirements//:requirements.bzl",
    "pip_install",
)

pip_install()
```

And the following in any BUILD file that I happen to need. Note that the py_requirements reference then will always be available for any BUILD file in the project.

```
load(
    "@py_requirements//:requirements.bzl",
    "all_requirements"
)

par_binary(
    name = "funkyserver",
    main = "src/main.py",
    srcs = glob(["src/**/*.py"]),
    deps = [
        "@mycore//:core",
        "@myother//:other"
    ] + all_requirements,
)
```

For piptool.py. You will need to rebuild the piptool.par using the update_tools.sh in the rules_python repo.

```
diff --git a/rules_python/piptool.py b/rules_python/piptool.py
index f5d504a..ab520d8 100644
--- a/rules_python/piptool.py
+++ b/rules_python/piptool.py
@@ -87,7 +87,7 @@ def pip_main(argv):
 parser.add_argument('--name', action='store',
                     help=('The namespace of the import.'))

-parser.add_argument('--input', action='store',
+parser.add_argument('--input', action='store', nargs='+',
                     help=('The requirements.txt file to import.'))

 parser.add_argument('--output', action='store',
@@ -154,7 +154,8 @@ def main():
   args = parser.parse_args()

   # https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/9.0.1/pip/__init__.py#L209
-  if pip_main(["wheel", "-w", args.directory, "-r", args.input]):
+  if pip_main(["wheel", "-w", args.directory] + [p for x in [
+      ('-r',  i) for i in args.input] for p in x]):
     sys.exit(1)

   # Enumerate the .whl files we downloaded.
@@ -219,7 +220,7 @@ def requirement(name):
   if name_key not in _requirements:
     fail("Could not find pip-provided dependency: '%s'" % name)
   return _requirements[name_key]
-""".format(input=args.input,
+""".format(input=" ".join(args.input),
            whl_libraries='\n'.join(map(whl_library, whls)) if whls else "pass",
            mappings=whl_targets))
```

Comment: Can you share your piptool.py modifications?

Comment: Or even better, can you make a PR? https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/blob/master/rules_python/piptool.py